# ¿Cómo salir del bucle?

Tags: html5, ionic, typescript

Estoy desarrollando una app en Ionic 3.

En un momento de la aplicación, en la zona del html, hago un bucle con *ngFor del cual, en el momento que vea que se cumple una condición, tengo que salir.

Por lo que he visto, no existe el break para salir de este bucle como pasa en otros lenguajes.

Este es el bucle que he nombrado:

```
<label *ngFor="let variable of placa.variablesplaca; let j = index" no-padding>
    <div *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera' && variable.orden === 1 && variable.valor === 1; else second" style="text-align: center">
          FCS activo
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera' && variable.orden === 2 && variable.valor === 1; else third" style="text-align: center">  <!-- Comprobamos si el FCI está activo -->

          FCI activo
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera'" style="text-align: center">  <!-- Comprobamos si el FCI está activo -->

          Semiabierta
    </div>
</label>
```

Entre en el caso que entre, tengo que salir del bucle.
¿Cual sería la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Había pensado en crear una variable en la declaración del bucle (j) para, cuando quiera salir asignarle un valor y que me salga, pero no se como cambiar el valor de j deasde la zona del html.

Comment: Lo mejor sería pre-procesar el conjunto y hacer el bucle(`*ngFor`) con los resultados que se van a mostrar en el html. SIn necesidad de sobrecargar el html con mucha logica, que es mas dificil de mantener y mas propenso a cometer errores.

Comment: probaré a llevar la lógica al typescript a ver si me apaño, gracias